# matching data in two excel sheets, and storing the data got matched

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets suppose I have two excel sheets. named *fruits* and *fruitsDetail*.

```
 fruits.xlsx                                          fruitsDetail.xlsx
**Name**                                        **Name  height  weight** circumference
apple                                       apple    25cm  50g      10cm
banana                                      apple    35cm  60g      10cm
orange                                      banana    15cm  20g     7cm
                                            banana    24cm   66g    6cm
....                                        orange    45cm  60g     20cm
                                            orange    36cm  76g     20cm
                                            orange    88cm  100g    30cm
                                                      .......
```

I have been using *jupyter notebook and using pandas*

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\fruits.xlsx','rb'))
mf = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\fruitsDetail.xlsx','rb'))
```

Now i want to save the data by circumference...
 output follows as below in separate excel sheet

```
name    circumference     weight
apple   10cm              50g,60g
banana  7cm                20g
banana  6cm                66g
orange  20cm               60g,76g
orange   30cm              100g
```

Comment: Do you want to compare if the whole row of the csv´s is identical or do you want to compare single cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to do a string aggregation on the weight column. For each name, circumference instance. The data is already all present in the mf dataframe, so there should be no need to merge it. Something like the following should work:

```
agg_df = mf.groupby(['name','circumference'])['weight'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
agg_df.to_excel("newoutput.xlsx")
```

Comment: It gave me error, for "sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"

Comment: Are the grams listed in your table just formatting? If so you would first need to cast the column as a string.